# How do I add buttons on a custom view in android?

Tags: android

How do I add buttons in a custom view on android? I am using a custom view but If I add buttons on to the activity using the graphical layout it does not work, I have put custom view on to the activity so it looks like this, but it still wont let me add buttons

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myView = new CustomView(this);
    myView.setGame(new Game());
    setContentView(myView);

    Button exitGameButton = new Button(this);
    exitGameButton .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    exitGameButton .setText("Done");
    myView.addView(exitGameButton);
  }
```

Then it made me add a method in my customView

```
    public void addView(Button exitGameButton) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Button does not show when I run it, also How do now make it change to another activity?

Answer (score 0):

Programatically just create a button

```
 Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

and add to your view

```
   myView.addView(myButton);
```

More detailed example:

```
private View v;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);
    CustomView myCustomView = (CustomView) v.findViewById(R.id.customView1);
    //Create button. 
   Button myButton = new Button(this);
    //Add button to your custom view. 
    myCustomView.addView(myButton);
```

Comment: also do I add the button in the graphical layout?

Comment: but then How do I sent where I want it to display? and what I want it to do?